# Why does this toggle function only work when the element is loaded a certain way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle some text, Q & A style with the question as a button that will display its answer when clicked.  It functions fine when the CSS does not load the page with target element set to display:none
However, I want the element to be hidden by default until the button is clicked.  For some reason, the js function does not work when the page is loaded in this manner. Anyone know why?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" class="question" id="q1" onclick="toggle_visibility('q1')">
        This is my question?
    </button>
    <div class="dynamic-text-wrapper">
        <div class="answer" id="a1">
            Here is the answer to your question.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.dynamic-text-wrapper {height: 25px;}
.answer {
    height: 25px;
    display: none; /*DOESN'T WORK WHEN THIS LINE IS INCLUDED.  But I want to not displayed to be default*/}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggle_visibility(questionID) {
var targetElement = document.getElementById('a'+parseInt(questionID.substring(1))); 
    if(targetElement.style.display == '') {
        targetElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        targetElement.style.display = '';
    }}
```

Comment: `console.log(targetElement.style.display)` before your `if(targetElement.style.display == '') { ... }` and you will see why.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/rDpec/

Comment: Works both [with](http://jsfiddle.net/cD3Br/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/cD3Br/1/) the CSS.

Comment: Actually have that in my source file. Now I see the result is "" on the first click regardless of the CSS setting on page load.  Why is that?

Comment: @wesmantooth: What else but `''` did you expect?

Comment: Because the element doesn't have that style directly applied. Why did you change your question?

Comment: @Bergi: I apologize but my original CSS had the wrong value.  I have edited to display:none on page load.  So I would expect to see 'none' on first click.

Comment: @cookie monster: Yes the original post had the functioning code.  It just works the opposite way I wanted it to.  That's why I changed it to display:none; which is conceptually what I am going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
targetElement.style.display = '';
```

you've got to write

```
targetElement.style.display = 'block';
```

In the 'if', you've got to check if you've established the display to block. If you haven't, the elment will be invisible (as set by the CSS rule):

```
if (targetElement.style.display == 'block') {
```

If you set display: none in CSS, doing .style.display = '' means that you're 'erasing' the inline value (which takes precedence over the value in a CSS file). So, by doing this, the new value for display will be 'none', as set in the CSS. By setting it to 'block', the final value of display is block.

I suggest you to read something about how CSS rules are applied.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Use

```
.answer {
    display: none; /* Hide by default */
}
```

and

```
targetElement.style.display = targetElement.style.display ? '' : 'block';
```

That is, if `targetElement.style.display` is falsy (you haven't set it, so it's hidden by default), you set it to `'block'`. And if it is truthy (you have set it to `'block'`), you clear it.

### Option 2

This option will make your function reusable with non-block elements.

Use

```
<div class="answer default-hidden" id="a1"></div>
```

And, at onload, run

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('default-hidden');
for(var i=0, l=els.length; ++i) els[i].style.display = 'none';
```

And in your function:

```
targetElement.style.display = targetElement.style.display ? '' : 'none';
```

Comment: There's also the option of messing with `window.getComputedStyle`, `currentStyle` and different implementations.

Comment: I really dig this answer with use of ternary style and the bonus option 2.  However, I gave the answer to Oscar as both solutions work and he answered first.